# Как отправить сообщение вне команды в дискорд боте?(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Вот положим есть такой код:

```
from discord.ext import commands

settings = {
    # ...
}
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')
 
bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Как вне команды послать сообщение?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846749/how-to-send-message-without-command-or-event-discord-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Импортируем `asyncio`
2. Создаем асинхронную функцию для отправки сообщения. Например - `send_message()`
3. Вызываем функцию через `asyncio`, передавая нужные аргументы:

   `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_message(762470056040330836, 'test'), bot.loop)`

*В данном случае `760470076070690836` - id текстового канала, а `'test'` - сообщение*.

Используя эту строку можно в любой момент вызвать функцию для отправки сообщения.

Пример кода:

---

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])

async def send_message(channel_id: int, msg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(msg)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_message(760470076070690836, 'test'), bot.loop)

bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Как только бот будет готов к работе (функция `on_ready()`), в канал будет отправлено сообщение 'test'